# Simple stopwatch in C

Tags: c, timer

A very simple stopwatch. Intended to be used for simple benchmarking when you want to do a task several times, but exclude some setup code from the benchmarking.

Some things I have already considered:

- Using the `restrict` keyword. I think it's overkill for this simple project.
- Adding error checking in case you start a non-initialized (reset) clock. I left this responsibility to the user.
- Error checking in general. Don't pass uninitialized pointers.
- Returning the return value of `gettimeofday` in `start` and `stop`. Very few people would use this.
- Returning `sw` in `start`, `stop` and `reset`. Chaining does not seem very useful here.
- Removing the chaining in `stop`. Basically just added it to motivate the return values for `timeDiff` and `timeAdd`, even if I think it looks ugly. :)

```C
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct timeval *timeDiff(struct timeval *out, 
    const struct timeval *a, 
    const struct timeval *b) 
{
    *out = (struct timeval) { .tv_sec  = a->tv_sec  - b->tv_sec,
                              .tv_usec = a->tv_usec - b->tv_usec };
    return out;
}

struct timeval *timeAdd(struct timeval *out, 
    const struct timeval *a, 
    const struct timeval *b) 
{
    *out = (struct timeval) { .tv_sec  = a->tv_sec  + b->tv_sec,
                              .tv_usec = a->tv_usec + b->tv_usec };
    return out;
}

struct stopwatch {
    struct timeval soFar;
    struct timeval start;
};

void reset(struct stopwatch *sw) {
    sw->soFar = sw->start = (struct timeval) {0, 0};
}

void start(struct stopwatch *sw) {
    gettimeofday(&sw->start, NULL);
}

void stop(struct stopwatch *sw) {
    struct timeval now;
    gettimeofday(&now, NULL);
    struct timeval diff;
    timeAdd(&sw->soFar, timeDiff(&diff, &now, &sw->start), &sw->soFar);
}
```

And here is some code if you want to try it out, but it's not intended to be a part of the review.

```C
#include <stdio.h>

double sec(const struct stopwatch *sw) {
    const double M = 1000000;
    return (sw->soFar.tv_sec * M + sw->soFar.tv_usec)/M;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct stopwatch sw;
    reset(&sw);
    start(&sw);
    sleep(3.97);
    stop(&sw);
    printf("%f\n", sec(&sw));
    start(&sw);
    sleep(1);
    stop(&sw);
    printf("%f\n", sec(&sw));
    reset(&sw);
    start(&sw);
    sleep(1);
    stop(&sw);
    printf("%f\n", sec(&sw));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's surprising that `timeAdd()` and `timeDiff()` return their results by both return value and out-parameter.  I recommend just one (preferably return value).  Though I do see that returning a value, rather than a pointer, is less convenient to use with the library functions.

---

There's no attempt to keep nanosecond values within the valid range of `tv_usec`, and overflows are ignored.  I think that should be fixed.  That's especially important for timers that might accumulate many start/stop cycles without reset.

If your target platform(s) don't have BSD/GNU `timeradd()` and `timersub()`, I'd encourage you to add your own.  Perhaps something like

```
static struct timeval *timeAdd(struct timeval *out, 
                               const struct timeval *a, 
                               const struct timeval *b) 
{
#ifdef HAVE_TIMERADD
    timeradd(a, b, out);
#else
    out->tv_sec = a->tv_sec + b->tv_sec;
    out->tv_usec = a->tv_usec + b->tv_usec;
    if (out->tv_usec >= 1'000'000'000) {
        out->tv_usec -= 1'000'000'000;
        ++out->tv_sec;
    }
#endif
    return out;
}

static struct timeval *timeDiff(struct timeval *out, 
                                const struct timeval *a, 
                                const struct timeval *b) 
{
#ifdef HAVE_TIMERADD
    timersub(a, b, out);
#else
    out->tv_sec = a->tv_sec - b->tv_sec;
    if (a->tv_usec >= b->tv_usec) {
        out->tv_usec = a->tv_usec - b->tv_usec;
    } else {
        out->tv_usec = 1'000'000'000 + a->tv_usec - b->tv_usec;
        --out->tv_sec;
    }
#endif
    return out;
}
```

---

Looking at how the function is used, it probably makes sense for `stop()` to return the total so far, so we could write

```
printf("%f\n", timeval_to_sec(stop(&sw)));
```

Comment: Is it not more accurate to use `clock`?

Comment: *"return their results by both return value and out-parameter"* - That is so that it is possible to chain them. Compare to most string functions in standard library. Like `strcat` or `strcpy`. It's fairly common.

Comment: Your second paragraph is VERY helpful. I totally missed that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I just find it clunky that the calling code always needs to declare a variable in order to call the function, but I see your dilemma when the library functions pass by pointer rather than by value.  I didn't sufficiently appreciate that issue when reviewing.  Your functions have a similar signature as `timeradd()` and `timersub()` that GNU and BSD-derived systems have; the differences being that yours are const-correct, have the result object first rather than last, and as you point out, also return the result pointer.

Comment: @TobySpeight I did consider the extra variable thing, but I did not want to use hidden globals or statics. Especially since that would make it impossible to have more than one stopwatch.